# Fatal Error During CMake Build: 'caffe/blob.hpp' File Not Found - Seeking Assistance

Tags: python, cmake, caffe, openpose

When using the command

```
make -j`sysctl -n hw.logicalcpu`
```

I encountered the following error:

[image]

I attempted to use OpenPose for the first time, and the installation process left me feeling hopeless...

I referred to the solutions for [Caffe errors](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/master/doc/installation/0_index.md#mac) on GitHub related to Mac, but I still encountered such errors. When attempting to reinstall Caffe using brew, however, the **`brew install caffe`** command has been disabled.

This is my CMake configuration:
[image]

Comment: Suggestion to set variable `Caffe_INCLUDE_DIRS` (include directory for Caffe) to `/usr/local/include/caffe` doesn't look correct when include directive is `#include <caffe/blob.hpp>`. You may try to set given variable to `/usr/local/include/` instead.